# Pandas: Subset of subset with multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, grep, jupyter

I need to grab a subset of the following using multiple conditions:

1. Event Type *must* contain the string 'Outreach'
2. **AND** *any* other field can contain the string 'STEM' - case insensitive.

Data Sample:

```
Title         Event Type    Presenter    Description    Tags
STEM event    STEM          Gloria       Bubbles        Craft
Robots        Outreach      STEM - John  EV3            Bots
School STEM   Outreach      Billy        Robots         Craft
```

Code:

```
cond = df['Event Type'].str.contains('Outreach')
stemA = df[cond]
```

This gets me all the outreach events.

```
cond = df['Event Type'].str.contains('Outreach') & (df['Presenter'].str.contains('STEM') | df['Tags'].str.contains('STEM') | df['Description'].str.contains('STEM') | df['Title'].str.contains('STEM'))
stem[cond]
```

I was hoping for a grep-like solution. The above gets me less than `grep` does on the command line and I know this result is wrong from looking at the data.

Comment: What do you mean be "grep-like solution"?

Comment: I wish there was an easy way to treat rows like strings and search the whole thing instead of iterating over fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this should work for you

```
cols_to_include = df.columns[df.columns != 'Event Type']
a = df[cols_to_include].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
df[df['Event Type'].str.contains('Outreach') & (a.str.contains('STEM', regex=True))]
```